# How to show the name of a help buffer in the tabline of the airline?

Tags: help-system, plugin-airline, hidden-buffers

I use `:h` command to open a help buffer. When I switch to other buffers, I can't go back to the opened help buffer. How can I show the name of a help buffer in the tabline of the airline?

Answer (score 1):

`:help` opens an unlisted buffer (`:help unlisted-buffer`)

You can make the buffer listed (shown in `:buffers`) with the command

```
:setlocal buflisted
```

Now you will find the buffer in the list that `:buffers` shows.